# it is good practices to use Strategy/Factory pattern in application, having one end-point ? Even the request and response are different

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design, strategy-pattern

Hope you guys doing well.

I am currently working on Rest Application and I kind of need a suggestion. So I have multiple legacy Java applications(5-6) and currently writing the new application to handle all those as a integrated service layer.

So the structure is all old applications will make a individual REST call to new Application with request payload and will get the response back.

> To addition to that, all the Requests and Responses payloads are not same and using different attributes.

and as per my lead, he said we need to use Strategy pattern for this new application so that there will be only one end point.
My Question is: In one Model(class; getters & setters) I have 40-50 attribute so Json Payload is already too big and some of them are lists and as for now I need to make Models class for other 4 applications which is having other 40-50 attributes, but to achieve the goal I need to add all those into One Model Class for following the Strategy pattern is that good practices?

Instead of this we can make a different end-point to specific request and response, in this way Json Payload will be easy for refactoring and to handle for future perspective too?

Comment: Likely a better question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?  That said, having only a single endpoint constrains you in many ways. What if one REST API needs to change/gets updated - how do you version it? What if you want analytics on which APIs are used and how often? What if you want to place different usage limits on each REST call?... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that your lead has a different goal than you do.  He/She is attempting to normalize all these endpoints, this is likely a stepping stone toward eventually normalizing the clients, and ending up with a single service instead of 4-5 different ones.

I'm not sure I agree with them from an approach standpoint, but the issue is much more a social one instead of a technical one.  As such, I'd really recommend you have a conversation with your lead and understand what the ultimate goals here are.  The goals are likely not "strategy pattern", but more likely "legacy migration".  If that is your goal, then this might be as much a discovery process, hoping for an emergent domain once all these are on the same service.  Or the goal may be something else entirely, and until we understand what he/she is trying to accomplish, we cannot recommend a solution as better/worse.

Comment: I think, you are right they might didnt share the big picture with me.